# Android sms broadcast receiver queue

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have a sms broadcast receiver that will read the sms aloud on arrival. I have a problem when the message is being read and then another sms arrives while reading.  Is there a way to "queue" up the broadcast receiver and wait until the activity is done before starting the new one?

Answer (score 0):

You can queueu messages in the Text to Speech

Example:

```
tts.speak("Hi",TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD,params);
tts.speak("Hello",TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD,params);
```